# Linear model for maximizing rank correlation between observed and predicted response

Tags: regression, correlation, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, nonparametric

linear regression is modelled as

$$Y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

for response variable $Y$ (vector), design matrix $X$, and iid Gaussian noise $\epsilon$ (vector).
instead of minimizing the mean squared error, i want to find $\beta$s such that the the rank correlation between $Y$ and $X\beta$ is maximized. So maybe the $X\beta + \epsilon$ term should be encapsulated it some sort of link function.

has this model been studied? is there a name for such a model?

if so,

1. how are such models fit and interpretted?
2. what are conventional assumptions of the model?
3. the fitted coefficients would be, presumably, non-unique, how would this be addressed?
4. what are some real world applications in which this model is used?

Edit:
I think I found a lead: [Modeling continuous response variables using ordinal regression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5675816/)

Comment: My criticisms of Pearson correlation [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114457/73930) willl apply to this, too. In short, if you multiply all of the predictions by $12$ or add $74$ to every prediction, you do not change the fit, according to either Pearson or Spearman correlation.

Comment: Specifying Gaussian noise and maximizing rank correlation imply contradictory aims.  Could you therefore provide some statistical context for this question to help us resolve that issue?

Comment: @whuber Doesn’t that comment presuppose maximum likelihood estimation?

Comment: @Dave It might look that way, but (1) specifying *any* such noise model, regardless of the description, is at odds with the aims and techniques behind the Spearman correlation and (2) even taking the model to mean an OLS approach would be acceptable is still at odds with using Spearman correlation.  I wonder whether the intended model is simply "fit $Y$ closely to $X\beta$" -- in other words, no probability model at all -- or if the Spearman correlation is a blind alley arrived at through some kind of analysis of whatever statistical problem is lurking here.

Comment: I think I found a start [Modeling continuous response variables using ordinal regression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5675816/)

Comment: [Ordinal regression](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) is a different kettle of fish that does not have the severe problems of using Spearman’s $\rho$ as an objective function.  The best objective functions are either parametric or semiparametric (as in ordinal regression) log-likelihood functions.

Comment: @FrankHarrell youre the last author in the paper i referenced!!! cool!